# ckeditor 5 tool bar is not fixed when more text is added in ckeditor

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

when we add more words in ckeditor and when we scroll down then ckeditor tool is not displayed and not static .

ckeditor toolbar should be stick to top even though notes are lengthy . so that when we scroll down the notes then tool bar should be visible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

with the [super build](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/39.0.2/super-build/ckeditor.js) of ckeditor, i don't need any configuration to do like that you want.

In any case, try this,

```
ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
            plugins: [ 'Essentials', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Toolbar', 'StickyToolbar' ],
            toolbar: ['bold', 'italic'],
            stickyToolbar: {
                shouldStick: true
            }
        });
```